# "Invalid read syntax: )"

Tags: emacs, parentheses

I'm trying to change the default font in emacs. I followed the instructions on the emacs wiki and added:

```
(set-face-attribute 'default nil :font "Avenir" ))
(set-frame-font "Avenir" nil t)
```

to my ~/.emacs file ( I believe this is my init file as I am on a mac).

When I try to run emacs again I get

> Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading `/Users/name/.emacs':
>
> Invalid read syntax: )

The debug message looks like this:

> Debugger entered--Lisp error: (invalid-read-syntax ")")
>   eval-buffer(# nil "/Users/rex/.emacs" nil t)  ;
>   Reading at bu$   load-with-code-conversion("/Users/name/.emacs"
>   "/Users/name/.emacs" t t)   load("~/.emacs" t t)   #[0 "^H\205\262^@
>   \306=\203^Q^@\307^H\310Q\202;^@ \311=\204^^^@\307^H\312$
>   command-line()   normal-top-level()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have an extra right parenthesis.

```
(set-face-attribute 'default nil :font "Avenir" )
(set-frame-font "Avenir 13" nil t)
```

Comment: On emacs wiki it is in that form. 

(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(font . FONT ))
(set-face-attribute 'default t :font FONT )

Comment: That worked though. They need to update their stuff: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SetFonts

Comment: It is almost certainly a mistake. Having unbalanced parentheses is not allowed in Lisp. Try it without the extra parenthesis and see if it works.

Comment: It's not a mistake -- what was on the wiki was *not* the same form as in this question. `(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(font . FONT))` is balanced! Unlike `(set-face-attribute 'default nil :font "Avenir"))` which is *not* balanced.

Comment: Additionally, I missread as I now see it says "put EITHER of these in your init file" and I used both.